# Shiny slider - retrieving values - list, or..?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app where am using renderUI in my server.R to create a set of sliders, since I do not know ahead of time how many sliders I will need created.  This works well on the webpage end, but I'm having trouble retrieving the set values.  Here is the renderUI function in my code:

```
output$sliders <- renderUI({
if (input$unequalpts == "no")
    return(NULL)
updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabSet", selected = "Unequal")
theSHP <- mySHPdata()
thestrata <- unique(as.character(theSHP$shnystr))
numstrata <- nlevels(theSHP$shnystr)

lapply(1:numstrata, function(i) {
      sliderInput(inputId = paste0("strata", i), label = paste("strata ", thestrata[i]),
      min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100), step = 1)
      })
})
```

Here is how I am trying to retrieve the values in a later reactive function of my server.R:

```
print("getting slider values...")
mysliders<- NULL
theSHP <- mySHPdata()
numstrata <- nlevels(theSHP$shnystr)
mysliders <- lapply(1:numstrata, function(i) {
    input[[paste0("strata", i)]]
    })
grtspts <-(mysliders)
print("input sliders are")
print(grtspts)
```

When I do this, the result of print(grtspts) is as follows:

```
Browse[2]> grtspts
[[1]]
[1]  0 25

[[2]]
[1]  0 41

[[3]]
[1]  0 22
```

Which his not what I want; I simply want the list [25,41,22].  I don't know why I'm not getting a simple list, but rather, what appears to be a list of lists?  Or .. I don't know; I don't understand what the leading zeroes are, there just before each set slider values.  How do I extract simply 25, say, vs. 0 25, from grtspts?

Comment: As a side note, instead of `1:numstrata`, you should use `seq_len(numstrata)`, because if `numstrata` is 0, `1:0` will return `1 0` which is unlikely to be what you want in that case.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare your `sliderInput`'s you assign `value = c(0, 100)`. From the documentation on `sliderInput`

> The initial value of the slider. A numeric vector of length one will create a regular slider; a numeric vector of length two will create a double-ended range slider. A warning will be issued if the value doesn't fit between min and max

You have created a double-ended range slider and hence are returned two values. To get the second value you can use

`input[[paste0("strata", i)]][2]`